# Zoom, pan and drag a Symbol in Flash

Tags: zooming, flash-cs5, drag, symbols, pan

I am trying to modify this script http://www.flashandmath.com/howtos/zoom/ to use a Symbol instead of an Bitmap image. Loading a .swf file is also accepted. Please advice, how can this be achieved.

I also need to make the zooming with the Mouse wheel, but I think I can handle that part.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks,
Diana